# How do you retrieve Chocolatey Install Arguments?

Tags: chocolatey

How do you retrieve Chocolatey Install Arguments? I know how to get params: `$pp = Get-PackageParameters` but not install args.
Specifically, I want to see if `--forceX86` or `--x86` flags are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from [Kim J. Nordmo @AdmiringWorm](https://gitter.im/chocolatey/chocolatey.org?at=59a067089acddb2407cb6a91) in Chocolatey Gitter Channel.

> @dhoer as far as I know, there isn't a way to retrieve all the arguments, just the arguments passed with `--package-args`.
>
> However, if the only thing you need is to detect if the user tries to force `--x86`, then you can check if the following environment variable `$env:chocolateyForceX86` is equal to $true

Example

```
if ((Get-ProcessorBits 32) -or $env:ChocolateyForceX86 -eq $true) {}
```